# How could I clean up this livewire component?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

The code:

```
<div>
    <select name="tags[]" id="tags" multiple
        class="select2 mt-1 w-full block rounded-md bg-gray-100 border-transparent hover:border-gray-500 hover:bg-white hover:ring-0">
        @if (old('tags'))
            @foreach (old('tags') as $oldtag)
                <option value="{{ $oldtag }}" selected>{{ $oldtag }}</option>
            @endforeach
        @else
            @isset($post)
                @if ($post->tags()->count() > 0)
                    @foreach ($post->tags as $singleTag)
                        <option value="{{ $singleTag->text }}" selected>{{ $singleTag->text }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            @endisset
        @endif
    </select>
    @if ($errors->has('tags'))
        <small class="text-red-600">{{ $errors->first('tags') }}</small>
    @endif
</div>

**select2 script init below inside @push('scripts')**
```

It is a livewire component that takes in an optional parameter named `$post`.
The reason I have `else-isset-if` is because, if you "edit" a post, the `$post` parameter gets that post object but if you "create" a new post, there's no post object to load up in the component. That way laravel still tries to read `$post->tags()->count()` which will throw an error stating "null" has no method called `tags()`.

That's why I've added the `isset` part.

It works but also looks extremely ugly. I have absolutely no idea what to do with it.

Comment: It doesn't look at bad as you think, it's clear what it does.
You could try using `@forelse` and `@elseif($post?->tags()->count())` to clean it up a bit.

Comment: This is the reason why I don't like to do create/edit in one form/component. It's a personal preference but I would separate them. Not much you can optimize heavily in your code, it's just if-else with all scenarios

Answer (score 1):

You might consider migrating your conditional logic into a Livewire computed property instead:

```php
public function getTagOptionsProperty() {
  $old = request()->old('tags');

  return $old ?? $this->post->tags()->pluck('text')->toArray();
}
```

Then, inside of your Blade view:

```php
@foreach($this->tagOptions)
  {{-- ... --}}
@endforeach
```

Your markup seems to be mixing Blade attributes with Livewire properties, so I'm not entirely sure what's going on here, but there would seem to be a good opportunity for refactoring.

Comment: Wow, your solution is amazing! I had to update a bit but it does the job amazingly! By the way, yes my stuff is kinda messy. It was a blade component but I tried to make it a livewire component, so I can validate it in real-time but livewire (on validation) replaces the select2 select with a regular `<select>`, so the entire thing breaks. I have no idea what to do from there since I've been struggling with Select2 and some wysiwyg editors to make them work (with livewire) and also make them reuseable, follow "SOLID" and others, for about a month now.